# Is backbone.js necessary for me?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

backbone.js has caught my interest recently as I was developing a webapp. Now I am starting a new app and is considering learning about backbone.js. I'm 1/3 of the way through a 3 part screencast tutorial on making a music player and my impressions are that the setting up of models and views were quite confusing and tedious. I am developing in PHP/Codeigniter framework so  I guess I have an idea of how MVC will help me.

But if I want to develop an single page (multiple tabs) app say, for store owners to manage their inventory, it can uses tabs that shows Dashboard, Inventory, Supplies, Sales, Assistants, Store Branches. Wouldn't a serverside backend with jQuery be sufficient without backbone.js? jQuery can hide display the different tab views, handle the interaction of UI elements, send and retrieve AJAX calls, manage modal dialogs... Why should I use collections and views when I can use arrays? In this case, how will using backbone.js help in developing this app?

Comment: Really just a matter of personal favours. Backbone helps structuring your app. If you're not using it, you have to make up your own way, if your app is complex enough (backbone is not a big library). It is not very hard, but challenging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Wouldn't a serverside backend with jQuery be sufficient without
>   backbone.js?

Of course, you could build your app yourself using jquery or even plain ol' javascript. It completely depends on the complexity of what you're trying to achieve.

Backbone is aimed at creating rich, single page apps. As such, it provides a structured means for describing, grouping and handling your data. Routing for application state, templated views etc. For example, collections (of models) provide so much more than arrays. They can be bound directly to your views, observe changes and automatically sync to the server with very little "glue" code.

If you're going to put much of your application logic in the browser on the client side, you need to keep it structured and organised. Backbone.js, and several other rich js frameworks do this very well.

Answer (score 2):

One of the nice things about backbone.js is that you aren't forced into a all or nothing proposition. You can start with just using parts of it, and use more of it if it makes sense to you. You don't need to use views for everything on your page, and for many things it may make sense to use a plain js objects instead of backbone.js models. You don't need to learn everything to start using it, you can start with parts of backbone.js and mix and match as you see fit.

One of the key points of backbone.js is to provide structure to your code, often the benefits of this (easier to maintain and make modifications/additions) are more apparent as your code base gets larger or/and when you need to look at the code a little later.

Answer (score 1):

While backbone.js can look appealing at first glance I completely fail to be able to adopt to all that unnecessary extra code I have to write to make things work. I've considered backbone so many times but every time I feel like it's just not worth it and I stick with a rails background and just the necessary jQuery to get me by.

I wouldn't bother if I were you.

Comment: backbone.js doesn't offer persistence or sharing of models etc so I don't see any real benefits except for having fun or learning. A better alternative in my humble opinion would be something like http://meteor.com/

Comment: Not all can and want have javascript server side.